# OpenPyXL でオートフィルを使って数値を自動で入力したい

Tags: python, python3, openpyxl

Python3で`openpyxl`を使ってExcelのオートフィルオプションのNOをA1から追加したいです。

下記のコードを使って行いましたが毎回データが不定期なので、自動的にB1（都市）のセルの最終行を取得してA1へ `No` をExcel で「1、2、3......」のような数値の連続データを入力したいです。

また `warn("Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default")` のエラーが表示されます。

ご指導をお願いできますでしょうか。

*国と地域数の列に空白があります。

**Excel Data**

| 国 | 都市 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 |
|  | フロリダ |  |
| フランス | パリ | 13 |
| 日本 | 東京 | 26 |
|  | 沖縄 |  |
|  | 京都 | 11 |

**Excel Data**
実現したい内容の結果になります。
元のエクセルのデータを見て
自動的にB1（都市）のセールの最終行を取得してA1へ `No` をExcel で「1、2、3......」のような数値の連続データを入力したいです。

**Excel Data Result**

| No | 国 | 都市 | 地域数 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | アメリカ | カリフォルニア | 22 |
| 2 |  | フロリダ | 22 |
| 3 | フランス | パリ | 13 |
| 4 | 日本 | 東京 | 26 |
| 5 |  | 沖縄 | 14 |
| 6 |  | 京都 | 11 |

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

#EXCEL READ
wb = load_workbook("test.xlsx")
#SHEET 
ws = wb['Sheet1']
ws = wb.active
#insert_A1
ws.insert_cols(1)
ws['A1']='No'
ws['A2']='1'
ws['A3']='2'
ws['A4']='3'
ws['A5']='4'
ws['A6']='5'
ws['A7']='6'

#save excel
wb.save('test2.xlsx')
```

Comment: 提示されたコードの範囲では Pandas は無関係なように見えます。 / タイトルも「～について」ではなく、具体的に「～したい / ～できない」のような書き方をした方が伝わりやすいです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。次回から上記のように質問させていただきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ワークシート内でデータ、もしくは書式設定が存在する最大の行番号は `ws.max_row` で取得可能です。ですので、以下の様にして値を設定することができます。

```py
#insert_A1
ws.insert_cols(1)
ws['A1'] = 'No'
for i in range(2, ws.max_row+1):
  ws.cell(row=i, column=1).value = i - 1
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記でも試してみましたこちらのエラーが表示されます。エクセルに変な文字入っているからでしょうか。`UserWarning: Workbook contains no default style, apply openpyxl's default`

Comment: エラーではなくワーニングの様ですが、`test2.xls` の内容はどうなっていますか？ `No` の列がきちんと追加されているでしょうか？

Comment: 確認しました。追加されています。ありがとうございます。`UserWarning`を非表示できますでしょうか。

Comment: 有効かどうかは不明ですが、`data_only` を設定すると非表示にできるかもしれません。`wb = load_workbook('test.xlsx', data_only=True)`

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記でも試してみましたがワーニングが表示されます。処理できているので一旦問題ないです。